# Draw parentheses in a simple way

Tags: swift

I would like to draw some kind of big parentheses around a view , that will take little memory (its inside a cell of collection view )

So for example I would like to remove bottom and upper parts from this simple circle view :

```
view=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.width))
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
        view.layer.cornerRadius=self.frame.size.width/2.0
        view.layer.borderWidth=0.0
        view.layer.borderColor=UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        contentView.addSubview(view)
```

Do I need to use bezier path ? if I do, then how ?

The simplest way I see is to just write "(" inside a big `UILabel` , which is pretty limited.

Comment: Why is your `UILabel` solution "pretty limited?" It sounds like precisely what you want (and kind of clever). Do you want more than it provides?